# Windows 10 - AppData\Local\Temp\

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to reinstall CCleaner but it is not the file...AppData\Local\Temp\ so it hangers up and does not complete the installation.

Can I create this folder or, should the CCleaner install program be creating this file on install?

Comment: It should already exist on any Windows system, but it's hidden by default. Any app ought to be able to find it, even if you can't. Click Start, then type `%localappdata%` to see it. Temp should be in there. What error message do you see, precisely?

Comment: You were right, it was there. 3 1/2 hours and I now have it straightened out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to reinstall CCleaner but it is not the file.

Uninstall CC Cleaner entirely (Control Panel, Programs and Features).

Restart.

Run Disk Cleanup (Admin Tools) and select the option (click on the button) to Clean up System Files. When Cleanup is ready to run, make sure you have selected ALL categories to clean up (delete).

Let it run (may take a while).

Restart and install CC Cleaner .

**Notes:**

The APPDATA folder will be there.  No issue.
Disk Cleanup will clean it up.

Use File Explorer Options to view Hidden Files.

That should work but if not, something larger has gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks John, I now have this CCleaner up and running.

Comment: Great that you have CC Cleaner running